# How to immediately return from simultaneous execution of async functions if any of them returns with success?

Tags: dart, asynchronous, async-await, future

I'm trying to improve the [internet_connection_checker](https://github.com/RounakTadvi/internet_connection_checker/issues/12). The code "pings" a list of given hosts to determine if a device truly has an internet connection. The current logic is enhanced enough that it executes the pings simultaneously, but it'll still wait for all of them to finish. Unfortunately if any of the hosts are slow (while the device has connection, just the remote host has some grievances) to answer then the whole result may take an excruciating 10 second timeout to finish, although there might be already successful result in the bag. I'm trying to figure out how to achieve that.

```
  Future<bool> get hasConnection async {
    final Completer<bool> result = Completer<bool>();
    int length = addresses.length;

    for (AddressCheckOptions addressOptions in addresses) {
      await isHostReachable(addressOptions).then(
        (AddressCheckResult request) {
          length -= 1;
          if (!result.isCompleted) {
            if (request.isSuccess) {
              result.complete(true);
            } else if (length == 0) {
              result.complete(false);
            }
          }
        },
      );
    }

    return result.future;
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is simultaneous? I am not sure but maybe it is waiting in the loop for `isHostReachable(addressOptions)` to complete and then comes the next iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following. We don't want to use `await` here (I have removed `async` from the method since that is useless now) since we want the loop to make all calls of `isHostReachable` without waiting on any of the others:

```
  Future<bool> get hasConnection {
    final Completer<bool> result = Completer<bool>();
    int length = addresses.length;

    for (AddressCheckOptions addressOptions in addresses) {
      isHostReachable(addressOptions).then(
        (AddressCheckResult request) {
          length -= 1;
          if (!result.isCompleted) {
            if (request.isSuccess) {
              result.complete(true);
            } else if (length == 0) {
              result.complete(false);
            }
          }
        },
      );
    }

    return result.future;
  }
```

Instead, we are letting the `.then()` handle what should happen in case of you are getting an result and completing the completer.

Comment: That totally makes sense. I don't know why I didn't spot that.